# how to fetch data from the these inputs

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying build a attendance page, all i want to know is,how to fetch the data from these inputs. And how should i name these inputs so that i could retrieve the data of hidden inputs and radio inputs.

This is the attendance page:

```
 <table class="table table-responsive">
            <form action="" method="POST">
            <tr>
                <th>s.no</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Roll</th>
                <th>status</th>
            </tr>
            <% for(var i=0;i<student.length;i++) {%>
            <tr>
                <td><%= i+1 %></td>
                <td><%= student[i].name %>
                <input type="hidden" name="name<%= i %>" value="<%= student[i].name %>">
                </td>
                <td><%=student[i].roll_no%>
                <input type="hidden" name="name<%= i %>" value="<%= student[i].roll_no %>">

                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="radio" name="status<%= i %>" value="Absent">Absent
                <input type="radio" name="status<%= i %>" value="Present">Present
                </td>
            </tr>

            <%}%>
        </table>
        <button type="submit" >submit</button>    
    </form>
```

what should i do at the app.js page

```
app.post('/attendance',(req,res,student)=>{ });
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/forms it's a nice tutorial.

In your case I don't recall if html5 submission appends the value to the request body you could do something like

```
app.post('/attendance',(req,res,student)=>{ 
     var nameone = req.body.name1 // or just use console.log(req.body) too see all props
});
```